# Using Hlines ruins legends in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-science, data-analysis

I'm struggling to adjust my plot legend after adding the axline/ hline on 100 level in the graph.(screenshot added)

if there's a way to run this correctly so no information will be lost in legend, and maybe add another hline and adding it to the legend.

adding the code here, maybe i'm not writing it properly.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,6),sharex=True)

BundleFc_Outcome['Spend'].plot(kind = 'bar',color = 'blue',width = 0.4, ax = ax1,position = 1)
#
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('SPEND', color='b', size = 18)
ax1.set_xlabel('Bundle FC',color='w',size = 18)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('ROAS', color='r',size = 18)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w',size = 20)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', colors='w',size = 20)
ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', colors='w',size = 20)
#ax1.text()
#

ax2.axhline(100)
BundleFc_Outcome['ROAS'].plot(kind = 'bar',color = 'red',width = 0.4, ax = ax2,position = 0.25)
plt.grid()
#ax2.set_ylim(0, 4000)
ax2.set_ylim(0,300)
plt.title('ROAS & SPEND By Bundle FC',color = 'w',size= 20)
plt.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc = 0)
```

The code gives me the following picture:

[image: result of above code]

After implementing the suggestion in the comments, the picture looks like this (does not solve the problem):

[image: result after changing legend location]

Comment: Move your legend to the side using `bbox_to_anchor` attribute.  
   `plt.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25,0.80))`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't keep the "Spend" legend color (blue rectangle) untouched, added the print screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWbsf.png

Comment: Try with no ncol attribute. `plt.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25,0.80))`  or move bbox_to_anchor further

Comment: As we don't have your data, we unfortunately cannot run your code to verify the problem. Could you try to add a third label, say 'test' to your `plt.legend` call to see what happens?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth The problem is not the position of the legend it is that the blue patch for 'SPEND' is replaced with the line from the `hline` call.

Comment: @ThomasKühn tried and failed 
plt.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc = 0) sends only 2 axes so giving it a 3rd label with no 3rd variable seems weird.

Comment: @Talis I understand the problem now. As a hack you can overwrite on the ax1 legend so that it shows both. Please check my answer.

Comment: overwrite on ax1? please elaborate

Comment: plt.legend creates a legend with line for SPEND and red_bar for ROAS. ax1.legend on the same position creates a legend only for ax1 with blue_bar for SPEND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using the builtin functions of pandas to do more complex plotting. Also when asking a question it is common courtesy to provide a minimal and verifiable example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). I took the liberty to simulate your problem.

Due to the change in axes, we need to generate our own legend. First the results:

[image]

Which can be achieved with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd, numpy as np
# generate dummy data.
X  = np.random.rand(10, 2)
X[:,1] *= 1000
x  = np.arange(X.shape[0]) * 2 # xticks
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = 'Spend Roast'.split())
# end dummy data

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,6),sharex=True)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# tmp axes
axes = [ax1, ax2] # setup axes
colors = plt.cm.tab20(x)
width = .5 # bar width

# generate dummy legend
elements = []
# plot data
for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    tax = axes[idx]
    tax.bar(x + idx * width, df[col], label = col, width = width, color = colors[idx])
    element = tax.Line2D([0], [0], color = colors[idx], label = col) # setup dummy label
    elements.append(element)
# desired hline
tax.axhline(200, color = 'red')
tax.set(xlabel = 'Bundle FC', ylabel = 'ROAST')
axes[0].set_ylabel('SPEND')
tax.legend(handles = elements)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use bbox_to_anchor attribute to set legend location manually.

```
ax1.legend([ax1],labels = ['SPEND'],loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25,0.70))
plt.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25,0.70))
```

https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location

Comment: managed to solve it on my own


plt.title('ROAS & SPEND By Region',color = 'w',size= 20)
fig.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc = 0)
plt.hlines([100,20],xmin = 0,xmax = 8,color= ['r','b'])

Answer (score 2):

So finally figured it out , was simpler for a some reason
Even managed to add another threshold  at level 2 for minimum spend.
[image]

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,6),sharex=True)

BundleFc_Outcome['Spend'].plot(kind = 'bar',color = 'blue',width = 0.4, ax = ax1,position = 1)
#
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('SPEND', color='b', size = 18)
ax1.set_xlabel('Region',color='w',size = 18)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.set_ylabel('ROAS', color='r',size = 18)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w',size = 20)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', colors='w',size = 20)
ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', colors='w',size = 20)
#ax1.text()
#
BundleFc_Outcome['ROAS'].plot(kind = 'bar',color = 'red',width = 0.4, ax = ax2,position = 0.25)
plt.grid()
#ax2.set_ylim(0, 4000)
ax2.set_ylim(0,300)
plt.title('ROAS & SPEND By Region',color = 'w',size= 20)
fig.legend([ax2,ax1],labels = ['SPEND','ROAS'],loc = 0)
plt.hlines([100,20],xmin = 0,xmax = 8,color= ['r','b'])
```

Comment: Better Solution. +1

Comment: Have a look at my solution in case you need it for more complex additions to your figure. It offers a more general (matplotlib centric) approach.